# Reactjs Access class method outside the class but in same file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have this code and want to access a class method outside the class in AssetsMap array.

```
import OrientationEnum from "../enums/orientation_enum";
import * as gameconfig from "../gameconfig";
import GA from "./analytics";
import * as Raven from "raven-js";
import {getQueryString} from "./tools";

const AssetsMap = new Map([
    [AssetsEnum.background, 'common/background.jpg']
]);

class AssetsManager {

    constructor...

    getConfigValue(key, defaultValue) { ... }

}
```

if I try to access `getConfigValue` method inside map array somethings like this

```
[AssetsEnum.background, 'common/background'+this.getConfigValue()+'.jpg']
```

the console throws error that getConfigValue is not defined. How should I access the method?

Comment: Why don't you declare  `AssetsMap` inside constructor?

Answer (score 1):

To be able to access a class method, you will need to have a reference to the class instance. E.g.

```js
import OrientationEnum from "../enums/orientation_enum";
import * as gameconfig from "../gameconfig";
import GA from "./analytics";
import * as Raven from "raven-js";
import {getQueryString} from "./tools";

class AssetsManager {

    constructor...

    getConfigValue(key, defaultValue) { ... }

}

const manager = new AssetsManager();

const AssetsMap = new Map([
    [AssetsEnum.background, 'common/background' + manager.getConfigValue() + '.jpg']
]);
```

If the `getConfigValue` method doesn't use properties from the AssetsManager class, you could also make the method `static`. Then it will become possible to use this method without having an instance of the class.

```js
import OrientationEnum from "../enums/orientation_enum";
import * as gameconfig from "../gameconfig";
import GA from "./analytics";
import * as Raven from "raven-js";
import {getQueryString} from "./tools";

const AssetsMap = new Map([
    [AssetsEnum.background, 'common/background' + AssetsManager.getConfigValue() + '.jpg']
]);

class AssetsManager {

    constructor...

    static getConfigValue(key, defaultValue) { ... }

}
```

Comment: well i get ```AssetsManager is not a constructor``` error when trying to create an object with  ```const manager = new AssetsManager();```

Comment: Is `AssetsManager` defined or imported where you are instantiating the class?

Answer (score 0):

You can't access the `getConfigValue()` method outside the class with `this` keyword. Try putting your Map inside the class.